# Volume of ellipsoid bounded by cylinder and four planes

Tags: volume, spherical-coordinates

I'm looking for a part of the volume of an oblate ellipsoid ($a=b>c$)
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} =1 $$

The part is formed by a cylinder $ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $ and two couples of planes:

- couple 1: $ y = \frac{L}{2} $ and $ y = \frac{-L}{2} $
- couple 2: $ z = -c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}} $ and $ z = -c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}} + H $ with $H>0$ (attention: this is not symmetrical as in couple 1)

I'm only interested in the part of the volume in the positive $x$-axes (positive a) lying between the cylinder (core drilled out from the ellipsoid) and the rest of the ellipsoid.
I already tried to calculate this volume by a triple integration
$$\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}}}^{-c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}} + H}\int_{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}^{a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}}}dxdzdy$$

but the integral becomes to complicated in Cartesian coordinates.
Is there another way (perhaps via spherical coordinates or by splitting up in different sections)?

Comment: Are you assuming $L < 2r$? If not, you'll have to add an extra integral:

$$2 \int_r^{L/2}\int_{-c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}}}^{-c\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}} + H}\int_0^{a\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}}}dxdzdy$$

Comment: Indeed $ L<2r $

Answer (score 0):

You're integrating over a rectangle, so a coordinate change can't really help you here. You can split it into two parts, but that won't make it much easier.

If you make some simple linear substitutions, and ignore the easier $\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$ term, you can reduce the integral to the volume bounded by an arbitrary rectangle and the unit sphere:
$$\int \int \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} dx dy.$$
This is an elementary function but it's still too long to be practical. Mathematica insists on expressing it with logs and complex numbers, but I managed to simplify it to this:

$$\frac{1}{6} \left(2 x y \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}-y \left(y^2-3\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}}\right)-x \left(x^2-3\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-x^2-y+1}{x \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-x^2+y+1}{x \sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Hi,
This is indeed a very interesting way. But I'm not an expert, how do I have to fill in the boundaries in this solution: x1 and x2, y1 and y2? Is it possible to add the upper and lower limits in this solution as well?

Comment: Call the long function I posted above $F(x,y)$. Then you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to write out the definite integral in terms of the boundary. You can answer your original question by making the substitutions $z' = z/c$ and $y' = y/a$. The final answer will be very long and won't simplify. It may not be a good use of your time to express the integral as a function of the constants in this way, depending on what you need the answer for.